# Two databases with the same data, are reporting different times

Tags: java, oracle, vert.x

I live in Arizona, MST with no DST if it matters.

I have two different Oracle Databases, that is storing a list of holidays and weekends.
The column that stores the data is a DATE format, no time value.

But when I use the API to call the first db for holidays in Jan 2021, it reports the holiday date at midnight. But when I call for all holidays in Jan 2021 on the second db, it reports it as all holiday date as 7am.

The query that the db uses is

```
SELECT *  FROM CLPUSER.HOL_DT WHERE TRIM(HOL_DT) >= ? AND  TRIM(HOL_DT) <= ?";
```

The API is using Vertx-jdbc when calling the db. I have double checked the configuration of the API and the db, all are using MST.

Here are the values that are returned from the API call

DB1

```
"publicHolidayList": [

"holidayDate": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"holidayDate": "2021-01-02T00:00:00Z",
"holidayDate": "2021-01-03T00:00:00Z"
...
]
```

DB2

```
"publicHolidayList": [
"holidayDate": "2021-01-02T07:00:00Z",
"holidayDate": "2021-01-03T07:00:00Z"
...
"holidayDate": "2021-01-01T07:00:00Z" //appears at bottom
]
```

Edit: Just debugged through the code till I got to how vertx jdbc reads it from the underlining JDBC library, It is reading the HOL_DT from the jdbc as a TIMESTAMP, when the db stores it as a Date Format. When it does that, it converts to ZoneDateTime at UTC, giving its timevalue.

Comment: Why `trim()`? That's forcing your dates to strings, which is going to confuse things. Then, how are you setting the bind values, and how are you retrieving the values - with `getTimestamp`? - and how do you then turn that into JSON? What are the DB time zones? (DATE values do have times - you just mean they are all midnight, I guess?)

Comment: Also are you really sure the column is a date in both DBs? It looks like one of them might actually be timestamp with [local]  time zone.

Comment: Just checked, Can confirm, both db are using the DATE Data type.

Comment: Something is different in the two environments then; I know you said everything at both ends is MST but it doesn't seem like that can be true. Somewhere along the way one is deciding it isn't - probably that it is UTC - maybe as a runtime change, maybe even from config it picks up from another DB table earlier. All you can do really is dump as much of the environment info as you can at the point you get )and set) the timestamps and see what's actually different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out something was different. When redeploying the code in one the environments, it started to show the "2021-01-02T07:00:00Z" like the other. My working theory is that for some reason one of the pods was set to UTC time, but now at MST time.

Also, the whole one entry being out of order was due to it not having Sort by function, and when I inserted all of these in Oracle, I forgot the first entry and it got put to the end.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯